# Change background-color of elements within an iframe on hover

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, background, hover

How do I change the `background-color` of elements in an `<iframe>`? The `<iframe>` is in my domain. Here is the complete code (HTML, PHP and jQuery):

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 

$url = $_GET['url']; 

if( ! empty($url)) 
{ 
    $data = file_get_contents($url); 

    $data = str_replace('<head>', '<head><base href="'.$url.'" /></base>', $data); 

    $data = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $data); 
    $data = preg_replace('#<iframe(.*?)></iframe>#is', '', $data); 

    $data .=  
    ' 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $("div").each(function(i){ 
        if($(this).css("position") == "fixed") $(this).css("display", "none"); 
    }); 
    </script> 
    ' 
    ; 

    die($data);  
} 

?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="author" content="Webarto" /> 

    <title>AdriaMart</title> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
//function for xpath location
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getXPath(node, path) {
        path = path || [];
        if(node.parentNode) {
          path = getXPath(node.parentNode, path);
        }

        if(node.previousSibling) {
          var count = 1;
          var sibling = node.previousSibling
          do {
            if(sibling.nodeType == 1 && sibling.nodeName == node.nodeName) {count++;}
            sibling = sibling.previousSibling;
          } while(sibling);
          if(count == 1) {count = null;}
        } else if(node.nextSibling) {
          var sibling = node.nextSibling;
          do {
            if(sibling.nodeType == 1 && sibling.nodeName == node.nodeName) {
              var count = 1;
              sibling = null;
            } else {
              var count = null;
              sibling = sibling.previousSibling;
            }
          } while(sibling);
        }

        if(node.nodeType == 1) {
          path.push(node.nodeName.toLowerCase() + (node.id ? "[@id='"+node.id+"']" : count > 0 ? "["+count+"]" : ''));
        }
        return path;
      };

</script>

//function to get  xpath location and write in textfield in focus
<script>

    $(function () {
  var selectedtextbox;
  $('input[name="myinput"]').focus(function(){selectedtextbox=$(this);});
  $('#iframe').load(function(){
    $('body *', $(this).contents()).click(function (event) { 
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
      var xpath = getXPath(this);
      selectedtextbox.val(xpath)
    });
  });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
iframe{width:100%;height:400px;} 
--> 
</style> 

</head> 
<body> 

<!-- ... -->
<input id="iframe_url" name="" type="text" />
<input id="iframe_button" name="" type="button" />
<iframe id="iframe" src="?url=http://kupime.com"></iframe>
<p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('iframe_button').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('iframe').src = '?url=' + document.getElementById('iframe_url').value;
  };
</script>
  <!-- ... -->
</p>
<p>Please click on title 
  <input id="" name="myinput" type="text" value="">
</p>
<p>Please click on Image 
  <input id="" name="myinput" type="text" value="">
</p>
<p>Please click on price
  <input id="" name="myinput" type="text" value="">



</p>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#id_of_element").css("backgroundColor","green");
```

Replace id_of_element with the ID of the element that you want the color to change for. And green with the color it needs to change to.

Comment: No I want to implement this on all (p,a,li,ul,div,img,script)

Comment: $("p, a, li, ul, div, img").css("backgroundColor","green");

Answer (score 1):

With css:

```
#id_of_element:hover {
    backgroundColor: green
}
```

Comment: No I want to implement this on all (p,a,li,ul,div,img,script)

Comment: Script doesn't have a physical size. And don't really get what do you need: all element's should change background on their own, or all of them? In the first case replace '#id_of_element' with 'p,a,li,ul,div,img', in the latter case replace it with 'body'